# Drools Fusion 'variablename' unexpected

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, drools, business-rules, drools-fusion

I am working on making a CEP using Drools Fusion. I have two classes of events ExpectedEvent and ActualEvent. I need to make sure ActualEvent objects occur before ExpectedEvent objects. However, I cannot get the *before* key word to work. This is in stream mode.

```
import hellodrools.ExpectedEvent
import hellodrools.ActualEvent

dialect "java"

rule "On Time"

when
    ExpectedEvent($expectedtime : getStart_time()) from entry-point entry one
    $actual:ActualEvent( this after[ 1m ] $expected ) from entry-point entryone

then

    System.out.println("ON TIME expected time: " + $expectedtime + " actual time " + $actualtime);

end
```

In IntelliJ I keep getting errors on $actual saying *'$actual' unexpected*. I cannot solve this syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to IntelliJ, although IntelliJ here appears not be reporting the correct error.

I believe the actual problem here is that `from entry-point` expects a String literal or a valid identifier, which will be used for the entry point ID (which is a String)

In your rule the "`entry one`" is not a valid identifier because it contains a space, and it's not a String literal because it's not enclosed in double-quotes characters (`"`).

You can try replacing `from entry-point entry one`

with `from entry-point "entry one"`